# Rotate a dataframe with header

Tags: r

How can we change or rotate the dataframe to be like the example below (First line represents a header)?

```
State1 Customer1 State2 Customer2 State3 Customer3 State4 Customer4
Us     1980      FR     274       DE     641       UK     521
```

Script:

```
State <- c("US", "FR","DE", "UK")
Customer <- c(1980, 274, 641, 521)

Table <- data.frame(State, Customer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base` way

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(split(Table, 1:nrow(Table)))
names(df) <- sub("(\\d+)\\.(\\D+)", "\\2\\1", names(df))

#   State1 Customer1 State2 Customer2 State3 Customer3 State4 Customer4
# 1     US      1980     FR       274     DE       641     UK       521
```

Another choice to use `purrr::imap_dfc`

```
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(split(Table, 1:nrow(Table)), ~ set_names(.x, paste0, .y))

#   State1 Customer1 State2 Customer2 State3 Customer3 State4 Customer4
# 1     US      1980     FR       274     DE       641     UK       521
```

---

***Data***

```
Table <- structure(list(State = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("DE", 
"FR", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), Customer = c(1980, 274, 
641, 521)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With just `base`:

```
  res<-read.table(text=paste0(State," ",Customer,collapse=" "),sep=" ")
  names(res)[seq(1,ncol(res),2)] <- paste0("state",1:4)
 names(res)[-seq(1,ncol(res),2)] <-paste0("customer_",1:4)
```

Result:

```
 res
      state1 customer_1 state2 customer_2 state3 customer_3 state4 customer_4
    1     US       1980     FR        274     DE        641     UK        521
```

Comment: You don't. Just use State and Customer.Or if you want replace State with `Table[1]` and customer with `Table[2]` in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("State1 Customer1 State2 Customer2 State3 Customer3 State4 Customer4
Us     1980      FR     274       DE     641       UK     521")
melt(DT, measure.vars=patterns("State", "Customer"), value.name=c("State","Customer"))[, 
    variable := NULL][]
```

output:

```
   State Customer
1:    Us     1980
2:    FR      274
3:    DE      641
4:    UK      521
```